# insert value in datatable and pass it into a mehod

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-3.0

i just use this code to insert value in datatable and pass this table in method
look code---

```
public class RoomBO
{
    DataTable dt;

    RoomDal objRoom = new RoomDal();

    public int insert(int room,string bedType, int bed, int charge)
    {
        //adds the details of the new room
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4"));

        DataRow dr;

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = room;
        dr["Column2"] = bedType;
        dr["Column3"] = bed;
        dr["Column4"] = charge;
        objRoom.Save(dt);
        return 1;
    }
```

---

****on data access layer****

```
public int Save(DataTable dataTable)     //adds the details of the new room
{
    ada = new SqlDataAdapter("room_insert", con);
    //DataRow r= dataTable.NewRow();

    ada.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room_no",
        Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[0][0]));
    ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room_type",
        Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[0][1].ToString()));
    ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_bed",
        Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[0][2]));
    ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charge",
        Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[0][3]));
    ds = new DataSet();
    ada.Fill(ds);

    return -1; 
}
```

**i am  not getting any error but value is not insert to my database**

Comment: @Aristos:i am  not getting any error but value is not insert to my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data-layer:

Try changing to

```
ada = new SqlAdapter( "room_insert( @room_no, @room_type, @no_bed, @charge )" );
```

Checking the ctor's for SqlAdapter it says:

```
   public SqlDataAdapter (
        SqlCommand selectCommand
    )
```

So the command must be complete.

hth

Mario

Comment: i think there is  mistake in RoomBo class ..because value is not added to dataTable .. i just see it after debugging

Comment: Shouldn't you insert dt.Rows.Add( dr ); ?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research: It doesn't work out as easily...

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308507 for details. You need to specify an InsertCommand and the use ada.Update .

My understanding is that a DataAdapter always refes to the same DataSet. I think it will be tricky to cheat the DataAdapter to work correctly...

Why do you want to use a DataAdaper at all (since you do not use it on a once retrieved DataSet?

You could just

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "room_insert( @room_no, @room_type, @no_bed, @charge )" );

cmd.Parameters.Add("@room_no", <datatype> ).Value = ...

return 1 == cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

hth

Mario